# Does angular4 support dynamic nested routerLink relative path navigate with hash router?

Tags: angular

I have a dynamic nested data like below, when I click the nested `routerLink` tag `a`, it not works and there is no error.

I use `hash` router not `html5` router. I want to use `relative` path navigate, from default route `#/tag-manager/sickness` to `#/tag-manager/department`.

I try `[routerLink]` directive and programming navigate. both of them not work.

```
[
    {
      key: 'tag-manager', routerLink: ['/tag-manager'], children: [
        { key: 'sickness', routerLink: ['../sickness'] },
        { key: 'department', routerLink: ['../department'] },
        { key: 'attribute', routerLink: ['../attribute'] }
      ]
    },
    { key: 'disease-center', routerLink: ['/disease-center'] },
    { key: 'doctor-center', routerLink: ['/doctor-center'] }
  ]
```

I render this `data` like this:

```
<aside class='sidebar'>
  <ul class='sidebar-nav-list'>
    <li class='sidebar-nav-list-item' *ngFor='let nav of navs'>
      <a routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]='nav.routerLink'>{{nav.name}}</a>

      <ul class='sidebar-nav-list' *ngIf='nav.children?.length'>
        <li class='sidebar-nav-list-item' *ngFor='let n of nav.children'>
           <a [routerLink]='n.routerLink'>{{n.name}}</a>
          <!-- <a (click)='onListItemClick(n)'>{{n.name}}</a> -->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

-- update --

I registry these routes, for example:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SicknessComponent } from './sickness';
import { DepartmentComponent } from './department';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tag-manager',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'sickness',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'sickness',
        component: SicknessComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'department',
        component: DepartmentComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class TagManagerRoutingModule {

}
```

`relative` path navigate not work. But `absolute` path navigate works.

Comment: Have you registered these routes with the router ?

Comment: Have you tried `[routerLink]="nav.routerLink + '/' + n.routerLink"` for child link?

Comment: @DeanChalk update question. `relative` path navigate not work.

Comment: @DuLin `commands: any[]|string` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L116

Comment: @yurzui I know it. But here I just want to use array type. and your solution is absolute path navigate. I want to use `relative` path navigate

Comment: You said that `routerLink` is array but now you know that it is not only `array`. Which urls do you get?

Comment: I change the routerLink to `absolute` path, it works fine. `routerLink: ['tag-manager/sickness']` and `routerLink: ['tag-manager/department']` ....